# $\phi : V \mapsto W$ a linear application. if $g \subset V$ a generator of V show $\phi(g)$ a generator of Im($\phi$)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\phi : V \mapsto W$ a linear application. if $g \subset V$ a generator of V show $\phi(g)$ a generator of Im($\phi$) and conclude dim Im($\phi$) $\leq$ dim(V).
I just wanted to know if what I have done is correct.

let v $\in V$ since g is a generator of V $\Longrightarrow$ $v= \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}e_{i}$ where $x_i \in K$ a field and $e_i \in g$. thus $$\phi(v)= \phi(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}e_{i}) = \phi(x_1 e_1+...+x_n e_n)=\phi(x_1 e_1) + ... + \phi(x_n e_n) = x_1\phi(e_1) + ... + x_n\phi(e_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \phi(e_i) \in \text{ Im}(\phi)$$
$\Longrightarrow  \phi(g)$ is a generator of Im($\phi$). If ker($\phi$) = {$0_v$}, dim Im($\phi$)=dim(v).
If ker($\phi) \neq$ {$0_v$} then dim Im($\phi$) < dim(v). $\Longrightarrow$ dim Im($\phi$) $\leq$ dim(V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct. However the reference to $\phi$ kernel is useless.

The $n$ vectors of $\phi(g)$ span $\mathrm{Im} \phi$ as you proved it. So a basis of $\mathrm{Im} \phi$ has at most $n$ vectors. Which implies that $\dim\mathrm{Im} \phi \le \dim V$.